# request vs ask; right usage;

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What word "request" or "ask" is more appropriate if we are talking about formal letter?

> 1. I am writing to request few days off.
> 2. I am writing to ask about few days off.

Thanks.

Comment: Request is much more suitable to use for a formal letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Request* <something>" = "*Ask* ***for*** <something>", so you could write

> I am writing to **request** a few days off.

or

> I am writing to **ask for** a few days off.

The phrase "to ask *about*" is less appropriate here unless you are looking for an explanation or clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really say why you are asking. If you are making a formal request for time off, then:

> I am writing to **request** *a* few days off.

But if you are asking if taking time off is *possible*, then:

> I am writing to **ask about the possibility of taking** *a* few days off.

or

> I am writing to **ask about taking** *a* few days off.